# Data not coming from database Mongodb Openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, database

I have created nodejs(expressjs) application with mongodb on Openshift. 
and I have pushed my database (mehendiDB) on the mongodb server which I can see on the server by using rockmongo cartridge as follows

```
admin(2)
api(3)
local(1)
mehendiDB(5)
  Comments(10)
  Likes(10)
  Posts(8)
  Users(9)
  system.indexes(4)
```

Though I can see the data uploaded onto server but when I retrive it with the following code from my users.js I do not get anything but an empty array. Code I ave written in users.js is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

router.dbServer = new mongodb.Server(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST,parseInt(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT));
router.db = new mongodb.Db(process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME, router.dbServer, {auto_reconnect: true});
router.dbUser = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME;
router.dbPass = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD;

router.db.open(function(err, db){
  if(err){ throw err };
  router.db.authenticate(router.dbUser, router.dbPass, {authdb: "admin"}, function(err, res){
    if(err){ throw err };
  });
});

router.get('/', function (req, res){
    router.db.collection('Users').find().toArray(function(err, names) {
      console.log("Printing output : " + names);
      res.header("Content-Type:","application/json");
      res.end(JSON.stringify(names));
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

PS : I am not getting any errors in the log console(nodejs.log) when I checked it. and showing 'Printing output'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the database name that you uploaded your data to is the same as the process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME that you are using within your application?